# Prove solutions of differential equations are tangent to each other.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u$ and $v$ be solutions of the first-order differential equation $x'=f(t,x)$, both defined on an interval $(a,b)$, and suppose $u(t_o)=v(t_0)$ for some $t_0 \in (a,b)$. Prove that the curves $x=u(t)$ and x=$v(t)$ are tangent at $t=t_0$.

How do you prove this> I totally have no idea on how.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I might be wrong. But if $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are solutions to differential equation $x' = f(t,x)$ then it follows that $u'(t) = f(t,u(t))$ and $v'(t) = f(t,v(t))$. Furthermore, if $v(t_0) = u(t_0)$ then at $t_0$ it holds $f(t_0, u(t_0)) = f(t_0, v(t_0))$ and hence derivatives at $t_0$ are also equal $u'(t_0) = v'(t_0)$ and hence these curves are tangent to each other at $t_0$.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say that both curves have common tangent line to say the curves are tangent to each other?

Comment: I would say it is the definition of two curves being target to each other.

Comment: So this question is actually an easy one lol